# ORACLE 12.2.01 selecting columns from different tables with similar names --> internal column identifier used

Tags: oracle, select, identifier

I wrote a SELECT performing a UNION and in each UNION part using some JOINs. The tables, which are joined have partly the same column identifiers. 
And if a "SELECT *" is performed, ORACLE decides to display the internal column names instead of the "real" column names.

To show the effect I created two tables (with partly similar column identifiers, "TID" and "TNAME") and filled them with some data:

```
create table table_one (tid number(10), tname varchar2(10), t2id number(10));
create table table_two (tid number(10), tname varchar2(10));

insert into table_two values (1,'one');
insert into table_two values (2,'two');
insert into table_two values (3,'three');

insert into table_one values (1,'eins',1);
insert into table_one values (2,'zwei',2);
insert into table_one values (3,'drei',3);
```

The I SELECTED the columns afterwards with the following statement:

```
select * 
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 1
union
select * 
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 2;
```

And got this confusing result:

```
QCSJ_C000000000300000 QCSJ_C000000000300002       T2ID QCSJ_C000000000300001 QCSJ_C000000000300004
                    1 eins                           1                     1 one
                    2 zwei                           2                     2 two
```

When the statement is written with tablenames to specify the columns, everything works as I expected:

```
select table_one.* , table_two.*
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 1
minus
select * 
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 2;
```

```
   TID TNAME            T2ID        TID TNAME
     1 eins                1          1 one
     2 zwei                2          2 two
```

Can anybody explain that?

I expanded my tests with two more tables to prevent double usage of table in the statement:

```
create table table_3 (tid number(10), tname varchar2(10), t4id number(10));
create table table_4 (tid number(10), tname varchar2(10));

insert into table_4 values (1,'one');
insert into table_4 values (2,'two');
insert into table_4 values (3,'three');

insert into table_3 values (1,'eins',1);
insert into table_3 values (2,'zwei',2);
insert into table_3 values (3,'drei',3);

select * 
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 1
union
select * 
from table_3
inner join table_4 on table_4.tid = table_3.t4id
where table_3.tid = 2;

select * 
from table_one 
inner join table_two on table_two.tid = table_one.t2id
where table_one.tid = 1
union
select * 
from table_3
inner join table_4 on table_4.tid = table_3.t4id
where table_3.tid = 2;
```

The result is the same. Oracle uses internal identifiers.

Comment: BTW, in real life, I would never use `SELECT *` in a UNION. Much too dangerous, the query will change or break if a new column is added to or removed from one of the tables.

Comment: Oracle is internally using `QCSJ_C000` as **column alias** to avoid the duplicate names and make it unique as you are using `*` instead of explicit column names.

Comment: @LalitKumarB yes, I know. But in the second statement there are dublicate column names as well. And ORACLE provides the columns with similar names ( or in some applications as Quest TOAD with _1 as TID_1 and TNAME_1). 

In my opinion the behaviour with the internal names as QCSJ_C000 is new.....

Comment: No, it's not new. DocId 2658003.1 refers to Oracle version 11.2.0.4.

Comment: @virtualbee No, it's not a new behaviour. See the DocId "wolφi" gave. It's a pretty old and known behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Oracle (DocId 2658003.1), this happens when three conditions are met:

1. ANSI join
2. UNION / UNION ALL
3. the same table appears more than once in the query

Aparently, "QCSJ_C" is used internally when Oracle transforms ANSI style joins.

EDIT:

Found a minimal example:

```
SELECT * FROM dual d1 JOIN dual d2 ON d1.dummy=d2.dummy
UNION
SELECT * FROM dual d1 JOIN dual d2 ON d1.dummy=d2.dummy;

QCSJ_C000000000300000 QCSJ_C000000000300001
X                     X
```

It can be fixed by either using non-ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM dual d1, dual d2 WHERE d1.dummy=d2.dummy
UNION
SELECT * FROM dual d1, dual d2 WHERE d1.dummy=d2.dummy;

DUMMY DUMMY_1
X     X
```

Or, preferably by using column names instead of `*`:

```
SELECT d1.dummy, d2.dummy FROM dual d1 JOIN dual d2 ON d1.dummy=d2.dummy
UNION
SELECT d1.dummy, d2.dummy FROM dual d1 JOIN dual d2 ON d1.dummy=d2.dummy;

DUMMY DUMMY_1
X     X
```

Comment: I expanded the test to prevent double usage of table names (see above). The result is the same, ORACLE uses internal column names.

Comment: Can you provide a link to DocId 2658003.1?

Comment: The doc is from support.oracle.com. Unfortunately, you'll need a valid support contract to be able to read the support documents.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting!

However, I would never use a set operator (`UNION`, `UNION ALL`, `INTERSECT`, `MINUS`) together with an asterisk (`*`).

The order of columns can change, maybe not by you but by somebody doing maintenance on the database, or by migrating your database to a new system using export/import, etc. Simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a INT, b INT, c INT);
SELECT * FROM t;
A B C

ALTER TABLE t MODIFY b INVISIBLE;
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY b VISIBLE;
SELECT * FROM t;
A C B
```

Comment: Yes, I know about that. But I am the only one changing that database ;)
And the statement was only used in a test case, not within the application.