# Using redundant table in ANSI JOIN query in Oracle 12

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

Today I faced an issue with SELECT result set, because - by fault - I put the same table twice into a statement using ANSI JOIN. And ORACLE did not end up with an error (what I expected) but seems to use "internal different" names for the table.

Perhaps someone knows if this is a described / expected behaviour of ORACLE processing ANSI JOIN. 
So here we go with my short example (that is not the SELECT with which I was facing the issue. That one was much more difficult ;))

```
create table a (a_id number(10),
                a_name varchar2(64 char)
               );
create table b (b_id number(10),
                a_id number(10),
                b_name varchar2(64 char)
               );

insert into a values (1,'name1');
insert into a values (2,'name2');
insert into a values (3,'name3');
insert into a values (4,'name4');

insert into b values (1,1,'something1.1');
insert into b values (2,1,'something2.1');
insert into b values (3,1,'something3.1');
insert into b values (4,2,'something4.2');
insert into b values (5,3,'something5.3');
insert into b values (6,3,'something6.3');
insert into b values (7,4,'something7.4');

select * from a
inner join b on b.a_id = a.a_id
inner join b on b.a_id = a.a_id
where b.b_name = 'something5.3';
```

The result will be the following:

```
A_ID    A_NAME    B_ID    A_ID_1    B_NAME         B_ID_1   A_ID_2    B_NAME_1
3       name3     5       3         something5.3   5        3         something5.3
3       name3     5       3         something5.3   6        3         something6.3
```

Obviously ORACLE uses the first occurency of "b" for the WHERE condition. That seems logical.

But what I expected is an error message instead of processing this query.
So my question to you: is this a feature instead of a bug?

Comment: Obsession with `SELECT *` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611705/oracle-12-2-01-selecting-columns-from-different-tables-with-similar-names-in

Comment: That is not the output from that code, the column names are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess neither; unless you call self join a *feature*.

If you wanted it to work differently, use different table aliases and use them as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a "self-join" - you're joining a table to itself. This should be allowed in any relational database. In normal use I would expect each usage of the table to be given a unique alias so that the values pulled from each join can be distinguished.